# ¿Como imprimir todas las coincidencias de un dato X con los hechos que tengan ese dato en SWI-PROLOG?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Estoy realizando un cajero automático, en este caso, cuenta con un estado de cuenta; aquí tengo hecha una base de conocimiento dinámica vacía, en donde creo datos según la operación hecha.

Sin embargo, al momento de consultar el estado de cuenta solo arroja la primera coincidencia, es decir, si `X` coincide con `estado(X, Transferencia, 300)` y `estado(X, Deposito, 300)`, solo imprime `estado(X, Transferencia, 300)`, y arroja un `true` después de eso, sin imprimir el resto de coincidencias.

Adjunto un ejemplo del codigo que consulta el saldo de la tarjeta y crea un hecho sobre esa consulta, también agrego una parte donde realiza otra operacion.

```
:- dynamic usuario/3.
usuario(4552, 452, 1000).
usuario(2554, 254, 500).
usuario(3698, 369, 2000).

% Almacena las relaciones de contraseñas y cuentas para cambiar las
% credenciales
:- dynamic contraseña/3.
contraseña(452, 4552, _).
contraseña(254, 2554, _).
contraseña(369, 3698, _).

%Almacena todos los movimientos realizados en el banco
:- dynamic estados_de_cuenta/3.

% Solicita las credenciales para dar acceso cuando se quiera consultar
% el saldo
consultar_saldo :-
    write('Ingrese su cuenta:'), nl,
    read(Cuenta),
    write('Ingrese su NIP: '), nl,
    read(NIP), consultar(Cuenta, NIP, _).

% Valida las credenciales y consulta el saldo de la cuenta y en caso de
% ser correctas, muestra el saldo de la cuenta usada
consultar(Cuenta, NIP, _) :- usuario(Cuenta, NIP, Saldo),
    contraseña(NIP, Cuenta, _),
    format('Su saldo es: ~w', Saldo), nl,
    assertz(estados_de_cuenta(Cuenta, 'Consulta', 'Exitosa'));
    write('Credenciales no validas'), nl.

% Solicita credenciales para validacion de datos para depositar dinero
depositar_dinero :-
    write('Ingrese su cuenta:'), nl,
    read(Cuenta),
    write('Ingrese su NIP: '), nl,
    read(NIP), depositar(Cuenta, NIP, _).

% Valida las credenciales dadas en depositar_dinero
depositar(Cuenta, NIP, _) :- usuario(Cuenta, NIP, Saldo),
    contraseña(NIP, Cuenta, _),
    deposito(Cuenta, _, Saldo);
    write('Credenciales no validas'), nl, menu.

% Solicita el monto  y realiza el deposito
deposito(Cuenta, _, Saldo) :- write('Ingrese la cantidad a depositar: '),nl,
    read(Cantidad),
    NuevoSaldo is Saldo + Cantidad,
    retract(usuario(Cuenta, _, Saldo)),
    asserta(usuario(Cuenta, _, NuevoSaldo)),
    format('Nuevo saldo: ~w', NuevoSaldo),
    assertz(estados_de_cuenta(Cuenta, 'Deposito Exitoso', Cantidad)),
    nl;
    write('Operacion invalida').

% Solicita las credenciales del cliente para obtener los datos del
% estado de cuenta
estado_de_cuenta :-
    write('Ingrese su cuenta:'), nl,
    read(Cuenta),
    write('Ingrese su NIP: '), nl,
    read(NIP), estado(Cuenta, NIP, _).

%Obtiene los datos y los valida para dar acceso al estado de cuenta
estado(Cuenta, NIP, _) :- usuario(Cuenta, NIP, Saldo),
    contraseña(NIP, Cuenta, _), estado_cuenta(Cuenta, _, Saldo);
    write('Credenciales no validas'), nl.

% Realiza la busqueda de acciones realizadas en el banco y que se han
% guardado en estado_de_cuenta/3.
estado_cuenta(Cuenta, _, Saldo) :- format('Su saldo es: ~w', Saldo),
    estados_de_cuenta(Cuenta, X, Y), nl,
    write('Movimientos: '), nl,
    write((Cuenta, X, Y)),nl.

% Solicita credenciales para validacion de datos para transferir dinero
transferir_dinero :-
write('Ingrese su cuenta:'), nl,
read(Cuenta),
write('Ingrese su NIP: '), nl,
read(NIP), transferir(Cuenta, NIP, _).

%Valida las credenciales dadas en tranferir_dinero
transferir(Cuenta, NIP, _) :- usuario(Cuenta, NIP, Saldo),
contraseña(NIP, Cuenta, _), transferencia(Cuenta, _, Saldo);
write('Credenciales no validas'), nl.

% Solicita la cuenta a donde se enviaran los datos, el monto y realiza
% la operacion
transferencia(Cuenta, _, Saldo) :- write('Ingrese la cuenta destino: '),nl,
read(CuentaDestino),
write('Ingrese la cantidad a transferir: '), nl,
read(Cantidad),
Saldo >= Cantidad,
NuevoSaldoOrigen is Saldo - Cantidad,
retract(usuario(Cuenta, _, Saldo)),
asserta(usuario(Cuenta, _, NuevoSaldoOrigen)),
usuario(CuentaDestino, _, SaldoDestino),
NuevoSaldoDestino is SaldoDestino + Cantidad,
retract(usuario(CuentaDestino, _, SaldoDestino)),
asserta(usuario(CuentaDestino, _, NuevoSaldoDestino)),
assert(estados_de_cuenta(Cuenta, 'Transferencia', Cantidad)),
write('Transferencia exitosa'), nl,
format('Nuevo saldo: ~w', NuevoSaldoOrigen), nl;
assert(estados_de_cuenta(Cuenta, 'Transferencia fallida', Cantidad)),
write('Cuenta y/o cantidad no disponible').
```

Para poder realizar una consulta en SWI Prolog con el codigo mostrado debe colocar "consultar_saldo.", con esto el resto esta ligado para pedir los demás datos, use los datos Cuenta= 4552 y NIP=452, después, use "estado_de_cuenta." para ver cuando se imprime el hecho de la operacion realizada, igual solicita datos, use los brindados anteriormente.

[image: ejemplo de consulta interactiva]

Comment: como llegarias a ese escenario? agrega por favor los pasos que tuviste que seguir para llegar allí y así tener un [mcve]

Comment: Debo llegar a ese resultado a consultar la funcion estado_cuenta; en las funciones del ATM agregue un assert(estados_de_cuenta(Cuenta, 'Operacion', 'Status')), para crear hechos en estados_de_cuenta y que el la funcion estado_cuenta sean recolectados y mostrados.

Comment: Para poder realizar una consulta en SWI Prolog con el codigo mostrado debe colocar "consultar_saldo.", con esto el resto esta ligado para pedir los demás datos, use los datos Cuenta= 4552 y NIP=452, después, use "estado_de_cuenta." para ver cuando se imprime el hecho de la operacion realizada, igual solicita datos, use los brindados anteriormente.

Comment: He agregado el escenario que comentas a la pregunta, pero no hallo la manera de realizar una Transferencia ya que el código no tiene forma de hacerlo, por favor edita tu pregunta.

Comment: Ya he añadido la parte del codigo de la transferencia, funciona igual que las otras operaciones

Comment: tras correr consultar_saldo. y estado_de_cuenta. no he podido reproducir tu problema, tal vez quieras modificar tu preguna.